# Radius Networks Beacon calibration with locate App

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, beacon, calibration

we are trying to develop a location app based on beacons.

At the moment we are trying to analyze different options and we are surprised the tests carried out with the beacon of the brand radius networks.

We have 3 radius networks dot beacons and we are measuring rssi values ​​at different distances. These are the results obtained with locate app (official of radius networks), we are doing 2 measurements per beacon.The 3 beacons are configured with a power of -12 dbm.

[image]

As you can see in the table, the results are not at all conclusive and it is difficult to obtain some kind of conclusion about it. Is this the expected result? How could we do to get some more meaningful values, perhaps configuring the beacons to less power?

Any kind of help will be well received since we are quite lost.

Regards

EDITED:

These are the results obtained with the 3 beacons configured with a power of 3 dbm.

The conditions are exactly the same for the 3 beacons, and exactly the same as in the previous test.

In this test can be observed that there is difference between the values ​​to a meter and 10 meters. However, the difference in values ​​between beacons at certain distances is surprising.

For example, Radius 1 and Radius 3 (-48,-49,-50) dbms at 1 meter and Radius 2 (-55,-60) dbms. These results have been obtained in intercalated measurements with the same configuration and conditions.

Since the beacons are configured the same way, and the conditions are the same always, should not the values ​​be much more similar between them?

[image]

Comment: What is the device model you are using to do the calibration?

Comment: iPhone 5s for all the beacons and measures.

Comment: 2 measurements may not be enough. Also, what advertising rate are the beacons set to?

Comment: We are not doing 2 measurements, the Radius App is supposed to collect multiple measurements and has an algorithm to get the value.The advertising rate is configured to maximun, 10 per second.

Answer (score 2):

It is normal for there to be a lot of variation on RSSI levels detected from beacons.  Calibration procedures are supposed to reduce this noise as much as possible by averaging the measurements over time.  The implementation in Locate is to throw away the top and bottom 10% of measurements, and take the mean of those that remain.

The results you show in the table are surprising, because the average signal levels do not get much weaker as you move from 1m to 10m.  It's not clear what is causing this.

A few tips for best results:

- Increase the transmitter power to the highest setting.  The stronger the signal level, the higher the signal to noise ratio, and the less variable the readings will be.
- Increase the advertising rate (packets per second) to the highest setting.  The more packets that are transmitted, the more statistical samples will be present for averaging.
- Remove any case from around the iPhone 5 that may be affecting the bluetooth antenna.
- Keep obstructions to a minimum in the test area, especially metal objects.

Full disclosure:  I am the author of the calibration RSSI collection algorithm in the Locate app.

Comment: Yes, although there is obvious noise in signal strengths, normally I do observe a significant fall off - probably about 20dB over that range? I'd guess maybe he has reflective surfaces around the beacons, like metal tables...

Comment: We are going to make new measurements this morning, then I share the results. Thank you very much